# Terraform variablization error Error: Invalid resource name and Error: Invalid string literal

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Hello Terraform experts,

I am comparatively new to writing Terraform code. Can someone guide me how to correctly use variables in below scenario.
I am trying to variablize the terraform code as below:

```
resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "${var.project}_lambda_layer" {
  filename   = "python_modules.zip"
  layer_name = "${var.project}_lambda_layer"

  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.8"]
}
```

and in my variables.tf file, I have this variable defined as:

```
variable "project" {
  default = "test"
}
```

but after running `terraform plan` I get below error messages(which I am not able to understand)and can't find a way to fix it. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid resource name
│ 
│   on lambda-function.tf line 70, in resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "${ ... }_lambda_layer":
│   70: resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "${var.project}_lambda_layer" {
│ 
│ A name must start with a letter or underscore and may contain only letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid string literal
│ 
│   on lambda-function.tf line 70, in resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "${ ... }_lambda_layer":
│   70: resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "${var.project}_lambda_layer" {
│ 
│ Template sequences are not allowed in this string. To include a literal "$", double it (as "$$") to escape it.
```

Answer (score 3):

Terraform doesn't allow interpolation in resources names you must use a common name in the resource like this :

```
resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "python_lambda_layer" {
  filename   = "python_modules.zip"
  layer_name = "${var.project}_lambda_layer"

  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.8"]
}
```

you don't need a dynamic name in your resource, you can identify your stuff inside of every resource with dynamic names

Comment: Okay, thanks @Derek for the quick note. Yes,this way it worked.